# How to configure karate-config.js and read values from it

Tags: automation, automated-tests, cucumber, karate, cucumber-java

I am trying to setup karate-config.js file in our project as shown in the below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cya8.png)

I have configured some test script in that file.

```
function fun(){
    
    var config = {
            host : "http://172.25.0.1:61047/abc"
    };
    
    return config;
}
```

Calling host from below scenario

```
Scenario: Generate Token POST
    Given print 'host --------------->>>>>', host
```

Output is getting nothing.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FlUER.png)

Anyone please help me here, what I made the mistake in the code.

Comment: you must be missing something. try using this sample project and comparing with what you have: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate-todo

Comment: @PeterThomas Thank you for responding, I have complared both projects looks same, I am using gradle build tool to run the tests, Is there any external gradle dependency required to detect karate-config-js file ?

Comment: read the docs, you most likely missed the configuring of the `src/test/java` part: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/Get-Started:-Maven-and-Gradle#gradle

Comment: @PeterThomas- Finally I got resolution for this issue, I just copy the karate-config.js file from src/test/java to src/main/resource. Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally fixed this issue, i just moved the **karate-config.js** file from src/test/java to src/test/resource.

Now karate-config.js file has been loading and I am able to read data from it.